# How to make a for loop to find interactions between several variables in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have a data set with 17 variables
[image]

the data is available at this link
http://www.uwyo.edu/crawford/stat3050/final%20project/maxwellchandler.txt

I want to find significant interactions between the variables.

For example

```
    fitcivilian<-lm(Civilian~Stock+Terrorism+log(Firepower)+Payload+Bombs*Temperature+FirstAid+Spies+Personnel+IG88, data=data)
```

[image]

where Bombs*Temperature is significant

What I want to do is test EVERY varaible against EVERY OTHER variable,

Like doing

Bombs*Temperature

Bombs*Napalm

IG88* Weapons

Missles*Firepower

etc. Till every combination of two is exhuasted

That way, I could find out if there are significant interactions between every variable.

I know how to do it manually, creating a linear model and then taking a summary of that model but I want to be able to create a loop that tests every variable because it would be a lot of entries to test everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had done something similar. You will need to modify the loop for your need. Let me know if you need help with that.

```
    vars=colnames(mydata)[-1] 
    for (i in vars)  {
    for (j in vars) {
    if (i != j) {
    factor= paste(i,j,sep='*')}
    lm.fit <- lm(paste("Sales ~", factor), data=mydata)
    print(summary(lm.fit))
    }}
```

Comment: Thanks! I can take it from there that was just what I needed.

Comment: You both should realize that you are automating statistical error. This is known as data dredging and is well-known to produce invalid results.

Comment: Incase this leads to a bias issue and causes over-fitting, the model will validate very poorly. Please explain what you mean by invalid results.

Comment: @BondedDust What if i set the alpha level to .0001? There are only seventeen columns of variables.

Comment: That would certainly be a great help in avoiding erroneous conclusions about significance. Choosing the proper alpha level might be a matter of some debate. If you have 17 columns there would be 136 two-column interactions, but your suggested alpha level for this situation seems reasonable since (.9999)^136 is 0.9864914 which is about what it should be. There is a `p.adjust` function that can be helpful.

Comment: how about doing variable selection first ? (forward, best, similar) There are some R packages specific for interaction terms for Lasso. Have never used those though.